How do I create a directory path in Sharepoint CSOM if it doesn't exist in an on-premise SharePoint Server?
With SharePoint Online, you have the option to use PnP Framework's EnsureFolderPath method, but modern PnP Framework does not support on-premise SharePoint servers. If you're manipulating files there, what are you to do?

This took me two and a half hours to solve, and the amount of code created is actually pretty small, so I figured I would put it online for posterity. I used a recursive solution for this one.
private void CreatePathOnSharePoint(ClientContext ctx, Folder targetFolder, string targetPath)
{
    ctx.Load(targetFolder.ParentFolder);
    bool querySuccess;
    try
    {
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        querySuccess = true;
    }
    catch
    {
        querySuccess = false;
    }
    string folderName = targetPath.Split('/').Last(); //Note that this doesn't work right if the last character in the path is a slash.
    if (!querySuccess)
    {
        string parentPath = targetPath.Substring(0, targetPath.LastIndexOf('/'));
        CreatePathOnSharePoint(ctx, targetFolder.ParentFolder, parentPath);
    }
    Folder parentFolder = targetFolder.ParentFolder;
    ctx.Load(parentFolder);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    parentFolder.AddSubFolder(folderName);
    parentFolder.Update();
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}

